# Find duplicate Files

Tags: linux, macos

I used to use a program `finddupe` on Windows (XP) which checked for duplicate files and offered to replace by hardlinks.

This calculated a hash of the 1st 32K, only checking the balance on match. I have the source (for VC++6), but was wondering if there is a `Linux`/`OSX` equivalent before I try to port it, although I suspect it may be better to write a new program in a higher level language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many similar tools. [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_duplicate_file_finders)
They may not be part of standard distribution.
I have used fslint before and found it to be sufficient for my needs.

Comment: You should include at least one in your answer.

Comment: Thanks. This is actually more useful than just a suggested solution. For now http://code.activestate.com/recipes/551777/ looks OK. It solved my immediate task, but I am sure I will try others

Comment: The link in this answer is dead, so probably the wikipedia page was deleted. http://deletionpedia.org/en/List_of_duplicate_file_finders seems to have a backup.

Answer (score 2):

I've found [fdupes](https://github.com/adrianlopezroche/fdupes) to be helpful for me.

If you are looking to write your own quick script, I would suggest looping over files and using `cmp` as it allows you to easily stop comparison after the first mismatched byte.

Comment: Yeah, I started down the same path as you and wrote a simple implementation in something higher level, but fdupes is fast and supports symlinks/hardlinks.  I expected this to be the directly acceptable suggestion.